# ElasticSearch - filter and aggregate nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to apply the following data processing:

1. get a subset of root documents using filter or query
2. for this subset filter nested documents (if root document has no matched nested documents, it shouldn't be excluded from the result)
3. get number of matched nested documents for each root document so that it could be used for further aggregation
4. group root documents by a specific field and get sum of nested documents count for each group.

I think I understand how to implement items 1, 2 and 4 but I haven't found how to get number of nested documents so that it can be used for further aggregation. Here is the mapping used:

```
{
    "store": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "categoryIds": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "campaigns": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "startDate": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "endDate": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are sample entities:

```
{"id":9,"categoryIds":[3,4],"campaigns":[{"id":9,"startDate":"20151130","endDate":"20151202"},{"id":10,"startDate":"20151130","endDate":"20151202"},{"id":11,"startDate":"20151129","endDate":"20151130"},{"id":12,"startDate":"20151130","endDate":"20151202"}]}
{"id":10,"categoryIds":[3],"campaigns":[{"id":10,"startDate":"20151130","endDate":"20151202"},{"id":11,"startDate":"20151129","endDate":"20151130"},{"id":12,"startDate":"20151130","endDate":"20151202"}]}
{"id":11,"categoryIds":[4],"campaigns":[]}
{"id":12,"categoryIds":[5],"campaigns":[]}
```

For example, I have filter for nested entities which matches nested documents (campaigns) with ids 9, 10 and 12. After filtering I need to get nested documents count for each document. For root doc (store) with id=9 count will be 3, for id=10 count=2, for ids 11 and 12 count will be 0. Then I need to group root documents by categoryIds field and get the sum of previously calculated values for each group. For key=3 sum=5 (3 from the 1st store and 2 from the 2nd), for key=4 sum=3 (from the 1st store), for key=5 sum=0.

Comment: Could you provide some example data, as well as the results you would expect to be returned?

Comment: Sure, added more detailed example